# Get username from all users in specific group

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I must be missing something here, or I'm blind or I've had too much coffee.
Basically, I'm trying to get the username of each user in a specific group i AD. 
Then I want to take these username and pass those to a powershell script. But that's another case. This is probably a quick win for you guys.

```
Dim groupName
groupName = "LDAP://CN=groupname,OU=MailGroups,OU=Exchange,OU=MainContainer,DC=MyDomain,DC=com"
Set objGroup = GetObject(groupName)

For Each strUser in objGroup.Member
    Set objUser =  GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser.UserName)
Next
```

And I get this error message `Object required: 'strUser'`
Why is this happening? strUser is right there!
If I change the snippet a bit to this:

```
Set objGroup = GetObject(groupName)

For Each strUser in objGroup.Member
    Set objUser =  GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)
    msgbox objUser.Name
Next
```

Then I get the result `CN=Doe John` in the message box for each member.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
For Each strUser in objGroup.Members
```

not Member but Member**s**

Comment: Hmm, I still get an error message: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. And this is on line 14, char 5. Meaning the line "Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

Answer (score 0):

This site will tell you more than you ever want to know about AD and VBS:

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/vbscript/vbscript_group_enumerate_members.htm